# RSS feed not showing in Android, working on web

Tags: android, rss, web, joomla1.7

My Android app stopped working on Friday. For some reason it's not being updated by the RSS feed - http://www.androidmobile.co.nz/?format=feed. The feed seems live enough when I plug that in to a webpage. I haven't added anything to the site that might have adverse affects on this functionality. The app is available here for free - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amnz

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that there is some sort of character in your feed that your app is not escaping or decoding correctly.  Then, because of this your app is not updating.  Check the last day the feed was updated, then check the content in the next days feed (where its most likely crashing).  See if their are any weird characters or quotes that seem like they could be causing issues.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Went over what I did differently last week. It was an embed of an adsense ad in the content. Removed and it now works!